# Where is information stored, that shouldn't nessecarily be stored in law but still needed in government

Tags: law, government, policy, bureaucracy

A law is defined as:

> the system of rules which a particular country or community recognizes as regulating the actions of its members and which it may enforce by the imposition of penalties.

Where would information that wouldnt fall into the category of a law be stored/written?

such as:

- office/job names
- salaries
- holder of an office
- code of conduct (e.g. how representatives adress eachother in the legislature. Although this is a regulation, it doesnt seem to be like a law, in which laws can be repealed)
- things that wouldn't be classed as "regulations" but are still needed to be written in some sort of doccument

Or am I completely wrong and these would all be in stored in laws?

Comment: The question is somewhat vague. Is it asking about only members of the government (congress, parliament, senate, etc.), members of a presidential cabinet/administration, the civil/public service or everyone in the country?

Comment: In many respects, an office in a government department is not so different from an office in any other workplace, so many of these things would be stored wherever workplaces normally store them. For govt, _some_ of that info may need to be public, so might appear on the govt website, or be available on request.

Comment: What Steve said.  Most of this information, about individuals, *is* stored in human resources / payroll IT systems.  Laws do not "store" anything so is that really what you are asking about?  Or, are you asking about the tendency of some police departments to store information on individuals that were not subsequently accused of a crime?  This [article re. UK DNA retention](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2013/may/20/police-retain-dna-thousands-children) is outdated, but can serve as an example.

Comment: I suspect that at least part of what you are asking about is labeled by the United States federal government as "Personally Identifiable Information" (PII) and a subset thereof called "Controlled Unclassified Information" (CUI). (The US federal government loves their "Three Letter Acronyms" (TLAs).) Those data are stored, but not in laws. Such data is in a protected database or spreadsheet rather than in a law, and it is not generally accessible. While a law or regulation might say that such and such data need to be collected and stored, the data are not stored in the law or regulation.

Comment: Laws are not just storing information but a process to make decisions. Storage is also irrelevant, because it tends to not matter where laws are stored either. Perhaps a better question would be how these things are decided (I suspect, that was @farderer s intention in the first place). That way an answer could talk about ordinances, administrative acts and so on.

Comment: An interesting question might be if this stored information should be made public somehow. After all laws are also just published.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Government agencies generate vast amounts of documentation in support of their missions in what are called "public records."

Laws and regulations aren't primarily places to store information. They are primarily binding guidance to government agencies regarding how they should conduct their affairs and duties.

This has been true back to the very earliest days of written government record keeping in places like ancient Sumerian and Egypt and China and Crete, and at all times since then.

Comment: Laws say "the President has the power to..." or "The Department of Justice has the power to..." They don't say who the President is or who is in charge at the Department of Justice or working there. All that information will be in public records.